# Using jquery to hide table rows before rendering

Tags: jquery

I understand that " $( document).ready " triggers just after the navigator loads everything at the page. My objective is render a big table in the page, and hide every row after the first "n-th". So, **¿How could I trigger a JQuery Instance, just before rendering, to avoid "blink" the table and the page's scroll?.**

I know that I can show at first the table's style as "visible:none" from first, but this is not a "valid" solution, at first.

Comment: Why not only fetch n rows initially?

Comment: I can suggest you to create your table dynamically.

Comment: If all rows start off hidden then the correct ones appear, it would simply look as though the table is loading rather than a 'blink' effect

Comment: The table construction and feeding is in a block of code which I can't touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally can't do that at **client** side. JQuery works just with the objects in DOM, that are available (or will be available in future - after the initial document loads).

I see two options here:
a.) **limit the number of records at server side**
b.) do what Bogieman said (load them hidden and show later) => This doesn't sound good to me since you may be loading huge amounts of data (generally).

If I understood your question correctly :)

Comment: My idea is to fetch the "table" or "tr" element visibility just before render, not after, but I don't know how to trigger it. So I think you understood the question perfectly.

Comment: I am not aware of any possible way of processing page life-cycle at client side. Even if you would create a JavaScript handler waiting for your table.. and somehow magically catch it in the middle of process, you still wouldn't be able to stop it after initial rows are loaded (= in the end you would load the whole table once again).

Answer (score -2):

$(document).load(); may be what your looking for, this happens before $(document).ready(); and it should happen before elements are rendered.

If this doesn't work, you may want to look at ajax calls to load then render the table after the page has loaded.

Comment: *"$(document).load(); may be what your looking for, this happens before $(document).ready();"* No, it doesn't. `$(document).load();` doesn't do anything. `$(window).load(function() { ... });` does, but it's *after* the `ready` callback.